# When I submit it online, they always says compile errors

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc

That's my code:
It works good on my mac. 
But I'm not sure is that the problem of Gcc version or not.
they said the sstream and string header are wrong.

1779655.134485/Main.c:8:19: fatal error: sstream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

here is the hint

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: I notice your file is called Main.c, is it possible that gcc is trying to compile this as C and not C++ which means it's not looking for the C++ headers at all?

Comment: which online engine are you using? asked out of curiosity

Comment: try changing code environment from `c` to `c++` and compile/run again.
@Borgleader probably you should put that as answer

Comment: cousera，and my file is .cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to include C++ header file in your `C program`.
Gcc is C compiler.

You need to rename `Main.c` to `Main.cpp` and use g++ compiler...